# Visual C# 2010 - Projects not running

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#

I made a project on one particular machine which works just fine, but when I try to run it over a network (as an .exe and by opening the project itself) it flashes for a second and then returns to it's default state. In VS C# it doesn't even turn on a window. This only happens for some projects though, others can run on any machine I want. Recreating the entire project fixes this issue, but I hope this isn't the best solution out there :).

Comment: What kind of application is it? Console? Windows forms? WPF?

Comment: It's a console app, a simply .cs file with code that runs in the cmd window.

Comment: Have you tried running your application from the command line (`cmd.exe`)?

Comment: Interestingly enough, it runs from the command line when I give it a direct path. Do you think there is something wrong with the machine I try to open the file on?

Comment: What is the name of the EXE file? Perhaps it's conflicting with something else on the machine.

Comment: Wayne Johnston is probably right.  The only reason an app would work when you give a full path and not when you don't is that something else is being run instead of what you intended.

Comment: You said "when I try to run it over a network" - how exactly are you accomplishing this?  UNC share?  Mapped drive?  What does the "Debug" panel of your VS session show for the command line?